# Move cursor to selected item position in bindView

Tags: android, listview, view, cursor, simplecursoradapter

Currently on selecting an item from list I have to move the selected item out of the view to make the cursor go to its position.I have tried using newView and all tutorials available on net but still not able to solve the problem.I am using a custom SimpleCursorAdapter.

Adapter:-

```
public class Custom_Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {


 private Context mContext;
private Context appContext;
private int layout;
private Cursor cr;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public Custom_Adapter(Context context,int layout, Cursor c,String[] from,int[] to) {
    super(context,layout,c,from,to);
    this.layout=layout;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.cr=c;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);


    TextView titleS=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TitleSong);
    TextView artistS=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Artist);
    int Title_index;
    int Artist_index;



        Title_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        Artist_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        titleS.setText(cursor.getString(Title_index));
        artistS.setText(cursor.getString(Artist_index));


     if(cursor.getPosition()==AllSongs.songPosition){
        if(AllSongs.isSongPaused!=true){
                         //change text view background color
        }
        else{
                           Do nothing
        }

     }
     else{
                     //Do nothing
     }

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_items, parent, false);
}


}
```

All-Songs class:-

```
public class AllSongs extends ListActivity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.allsongs);

    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"; //----->Use for all songs


    lv=getListView();

    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

     String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,

        };
        //query 

        musiccursor = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,selection,null,sortOrder);
        music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        count = musiccursor.getCount();
        int a[]= new int[]{R.id.TitleSong,R.id.Artist};


       Custom_Adapter adapter=new Custom_Adapter(this, R.layout.music_items, musiccursor, new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST},a);



        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

}

@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
 }
```

Comment: why do you use bindView with SimpleCursorAdapter? any serious reason?

Comment: I checked various tutorials and they all were suggesting to use bindView instead of getView if I am extending SimpleCursorAdapter.Should I go for getView?

Comment: no for SimpleCursorAdapter you dont need to extend either bindVuew or getView, all the job is done by SimpleCursorAdapter, in some cases however where mapping is not trivial you can use ViewBinder interface

Comment: Then how should I do it?

Comment: how do you create Custom_Adapter? what are "from" and "to" params?

Comment: Check my updated question.And everything is working fine I just want to know how to move the cursor.

Comment: you dont need to call titleS.setText and artistS.setText, it is done by SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: Can you tell me how to move the cursor to selected item position because everything is working fine.